# screen mirroring from android tv box to smartphone

Tags: android-tv, screencast, screen-mirroring

I want the opposite of screen mirroring, from android tv box to smartphone.
Reason I want remote control apps on android tv box with smartphone but avoid over the air streaming.

The android tv box is rooted and connected via ethernet LAN port to my home network.

Google TV and other screen cast apps require wifi enabled on tv box (which is disabled). I prefer solution over TCP/IP. scrcpy can control over adb which works on tcpip too, but it's for PC. Therefore I am fine with middle solution control PC from smartphone + control tv box from PC

What can I do?

Comment: If you just need to control your AndroidTV without viewing the screen on the smartphone you can use your phone as remote control: https://support.google.com/androidtv/answer/6122465?hl=en

Comment: tried *com.ecloud.eshare.server* it works but unfortunately touch input does not control tv (you can extract apk from Beelink S82 Plus TV Box firmware [here](http://chinagadgetsreviews.blogspot.ro/2015/03/download-latest-android-kitkat-442_21.html))

Comment: gms is outdated and does not support android 7.1.1 tv box for some reason. therefore cannot use google tv

Comment: was able to install [CetusPlay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cetusplay.remoteservice) on set top box. it can share screen or remote control at least. unfortunately not simultaneously, that are two separate modes. maybe I should try teamviewer?

Comment: couldn't get teamviewer to work